# Is there a way to use ASP.NET client side validation controls to change the text of a label?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am hoping to change the text of a label based on the outcome of a client side validation control.  Is there any way to do this using the regular expression validation control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming client-side validation is enabled for the Valdiator.  There is a client-side API you can hook into to.  See this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Scroll down and read the "Special Effects" section, which uses a RegularExpressionValidator in the example.  Note that it changes the background color rather than changing text in a label, but the main thing is seeing where you can put your own code.  Also note that you can't change the *server* representation of the label.  All you can do is normal javascript DOM manipulation.

Comment: This came really close but I haven't been able to change any of the labels in my page.  Essentially nothing happen even though the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of directly, but what you can do is override the validation functions for the validators and have that update the label.

This isn't the [post](http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2009/07/aspnet-how-to-trigger-client-side.html) I initially found that describes it, but I believe it will point you in the right direction.